# How is an arbitrary member of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ defined?

Tags: ring-theory, extension-field

How is arbitrary member of  $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ defined? $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ means the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\pi$
, thanks

I thought maybe it's

$$x+y\pi,\quad x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$$

but how to get $$\pi^2=x+y\pi$$ or $$1/\pi$$

with that?

Comment: Since $\pi $ is transcendental, $\Bbb Q (\pi) $ is an infinite extension. So I think your approach is wrong.

Comment: It simply comprises all rational fractions in $\pi$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: @Bernard can you give examples of this please? in there a general expression?

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe that $\pi^2$ and $\frac{1}{\pi}$ **are** in Q(π)?

Comment: @user247327 by definition $\pi$ is in, so from closure and inverses, those two numbers are also in!

Comment: @Thomas Shelby I think a typical element is  $p(\pi) / q(\pi)$, $p, q \in Q[x]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Bbb Q(x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q(π)$,  by sending $x$ to $π$. So, no typical element is of the form $x+πy$, as that'd mean we are dealing with a degree $2$ extension, but $\Bbb Q(π)$ is an infinite extension. This is always the case when you adjoin a transcedental number to $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: make sense! thanks

Comment: I think a typical element is  $p(\pi) / q(\pi)$, $p, q \in Q[x]$